# mvc 5 SelectList from table with blank value for DropDownList

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I am using below code to create a drop down

**Controller**

```
ViewBag.Id= new SelectList(db.TableName.OrderBy(x => x.Name),"Id","Name")
```

**View**

```
 @Html.DropDownList("Id", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
```

My question is how can I Modify `SelectList` to add a blank item so that there is a blank item automatically added for `DropDownList`.

Thanks.

Answer (score 74, accepted):

Use one of the [overloads](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.selectextensions.dropdownlistfor(v=vs.118).aspx#M:System.Web.Mvc.Html.SelectExtensions.DropDownListFor<code>2%28System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper%7B</code>0%7D,System.Linq.Expressions.Expression%7BSystem.Func%7B<code>0,</code>1%7D%7D,System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable%7BSystem.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem%7D,System.String%29) that accepts an `optionLabel`

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.ID, (SelectList)ViewBag.MyList, "Please select", new { @class = "form-control" })
```

or if you do not want to use the strongly typed methods

```
@Html.DropDownList("ID", (SelectList)ViewBag.MyList, "Please select", new { @class = "form-control" })
```

Which will add the first option with the text specified in the 3rd parameter and with a `null` value

```
<option value="">Please Select</option>
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. So I cannot modify the SelectList to get the desired result?

Comment: No, but why would you want to? You could always create your own `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` and add insert the first one with `Text="..."` and `Value=""` but that really makes no sense

Comment: Because I want to decide in controller to have blank value of not. There will be case where there will be no blank value.

Comment: And I see you have just edited your question to change `ViewBag.MyList` to `ViewBag.ID`. I recommend you follow best practice and use a different name for the property your binding to and the name of the `SelectList`

Comment: In that case you must build your own `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` (`SelectList` has no constructor that adds a blank (`null`) option.

Comment: Yes I noticed the problem in code and fixed it with proper comment.I will study your advice. Thanks for answers. This answers all.

Answer (score 3):

You can use this overload:

```
public static MvcHtmlString DropDownList(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, string name, IEnumerable<SelectListItem> selectList, string optionLabel, object htmlAttributes);
```

where `optionLabel` is the text for a default empty item.

Comment: Can you give an example please. Also I want to add empty value " " with with id say -1 to SelectList. Thanks.

Comment: For example:  `@Html.DropDownList("Id", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control", optionLabel: "[not selected]" })` If the text "[not selected]" is selected then you will get _null_ as a value.

Comment: I am getting error" The best overloaded for "DropDownList" dosen't have a parameter named optionLabel "

Comment: @ary This should compile: `@Html.DropDownList("Id", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control"}, optionLabel: "[not selected]")`

Answer (score 2):

In my project, these work:

Controller

```
ViewBag.TagHfoFlagId= new SelectList(db.TableName.OrderBy(x => x.Name),"Id","Name")
```

View

```
 @Html.DropDownList("TagHfoFlagId", null,"--Select Name--", htmlAttributes: new { @id = "tags" })
```

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer does work, but it will show the default (null) value in the view's drop down list even if you already selected one before. If you want the already selected value to show itself in the drop down list once you render back the view, use this instead :

**Controller**

```
ViewBag.Fk_Id_Parent_Table = new SelectList(db.Parent_Table, "Id", "Name", Child_Table.Fk_Id_Parent_Table);
return View(ChildTable);
```

**View**

```
@Html.DropDownList(
             "Fk_Id_Parent_Table",
             null, 
             "Not Assigned", 
             htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" }
                  )
```