# Why doesn't Bootstrap Select show selected value when I include a default?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-select

When I have an object with a value set, it is only shown initially if I leave out the `"--Select--"` parameter.

Any idea why that would be?

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.FlightDetails.AirlineId, ViewBag.AirlineList as SelectList, "--Select--", new { @class = "form-control selectpicker", @data_live_search = "true", @id = flight.Id + "AirlineId" })
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Html.DropdownListFor selected value not being set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19476530/html-dropdownlistfor-selected-value-not-being-set)

Comment: @ZorgoZ No it does not

Comment: It should. How are you populating your SelectList?

Comment: Check this out: https://nimblegecko.com/how-to-set-default-selected-value-on-drop-down-list-from-database/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that this was my issue: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52431696/6591937.

I can't set the selected value when creating the SelectList because I'm using the same SelectList in more that one place and they all can have different values.

The way I resolved it in my case was that I passed in "--Select--" and I set the value via javascript (as I'm accessing it only via javascript anyway).

Answer (score 0):

**Server-side**:

You should set a default value for third params, look like this (Pay attention to `SelectedDefaultValueHere`)

```
var ViewBag.AirlineList = new SelectList(`listOfItemHere`,
    "ValueOfDropdownItem", 
    "TextToDisplay",  
    SelectedDefaultValueHere);
```

Or You can set `Selected` of `SelectListItem` like this

```
new SelectListItem()
{
   Value = "anyValue",
   Text = "AnyText",
   Selected = true
};
```